# Error: spawn pycodestyle ENOENT

Tags: atom-editor, autopep8

I got this error having linter-pep8 installed.

```
Error: spawn pycodestyle ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error is caused by package being renamed from **linter-pep8** to **linter-pycodestyle** v2.0.0

**Solution**:

1. Uninstall **pep8** `sudo pip uninstall pep8`
2. Uninstall **pycodestyle** `sudo pip uninstall pycodestyle`
3. Again installing **pycodestyle** `sudo pip install pycodestyle`
4. Uninstall ATOM **linter-pep8** package  `apm uninstall linter-pep8`
5. Installing ATOM **linter-pycodestyle** package `apm install linter-pycodestyle`
6. Check if **pycodestyle** was installed correctly by executing `which pycodestyle` in terminal. It should return path to **pycodestyle**  (eg. `/usr/local/bin/pycodestyle`). You might set this path in **Executable Path** setting of atoms' **linter-pycodestyle** package -but it should work by default

Comment: I had to reinstall pep8 to get this to work - after running this, I ran into the error `spawn pep8 ENOENT`, which was fixed by running `sudo pip install pep8`.